# Confused about conversion between windows-1252 and UTF-8 encoding

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, windows-1252

I have a legacy database that claims to have collation set to windows-1252 and is storing a text field's contents as

`Iâ€™d`

When it is displayed in a legacy web-app it shows as `I’d` in the browser.  The browser reports a page encoding of UTF-8.  I can't figure out how that conversion has been done (almost certain it isn't via an on-the-fly search-and-replace).  This is a problem for me because I am taking the text field (and many others like it) from the legacy database and into a new UTF-8 database.  A new web app displays the text from the new database as

`Iâ€™d`

and I would like it to show it as `I’d`.  I can't figure out how the legacy app could have achieved this (some fiddling in Ruby hasn't showed me a way to affect converting a string `Iâ€™d` to `I’d`).

I've tied myself in a knot here somewhere.

Comment: Your dbase contains junk.  Inserted by a program that ignored the encoding and used utf8.  And as luck would have it, read by a program that ignored it as well.  Not usually luck.  It works 99% right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably means the previous developer screwed up data insertion (or you're screwing up somewhere). The scenario goes like this:

- the **database connection** is set to `latin1`
- app actually sends UTF-8 to database
- database interprets received data as `latin1`, stores it as such (interprets ’ as â€™)
- app queries for the data again
- database returns â€™ encoded in `latin1`
- app interprets the data as UTF-8, resulting in ’

You essentially need to do the same misinterpretation to get good data. Right now you may be querying the database through a `utf8` connection, so the database returns â€™ encoded in UTF-8. What you need to do is query through a `latin1` connection and interpret the data as UTF-8 instead.

See [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) for a more detailed explanation of all this.

Comment: Yes that makes sense thanks @deceze. I'd like to do a one off conversion then. Don't want to touch the old database.